# Apply promise to request in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, promise

I am trying to manage contacts feed received from google in my Controller.The feed is passed from the front end using a POST request. The request is quite large having hundreds of entries. When I try to parse the feed as

```
Document document = request().body().asXml();
```

it fails with the following exception.

```
2014-11-03_12:33:41.948 DEBUG play - Invalid Json
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING
at [Source: [B@79c1d9a1; line: 1, column: 204801]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1524) ~[jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:557) ~[jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(ParserMinimalBase.java:487) ~[jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(P
.
.
.
```

I think its because the request was not fully loaded and I am trying to parse an incomplete request leading to an invalid Json. How can I apply Promise to the request(). Could someone help me?

Comment: What is content type of response?

Comment: Please post the full controller function.

Comment: @MonCalamari The content is the contacts feed of a user obtained using google api.

Comment: @m-z, the exception is caused by this line only
   Document document = request().body().asXml();
Rest of the controller are function calls to process this document.
I have tried commenting out rest of the lines and still get the exception.

Comment: @ShabinMuhammed But the signature of the function is important. That line by itself is worthless.

Comment: @m-z, I have resolved the problem by processing the contacts feed in front end using javascript. Now I send an object array from front end via POST to the controller. Works fine now.

Apologies for wasting your time. :(